# Previously no-tracking entities get tracked upon calling Savechages(). Is this normal?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a simple controller in which I create and add a user and a profile to the database

```
    public async ActionResult AddUserAndProfile(string id)
    {
        _context.Users.Add(new User { Id = id });
        _context.SaveChanges(); // If this line is removed, error doesn't occur.

        var profile = new Profile
        {
            Id = "id",
            User = _context.Users.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id.Equals(id))
        }; // Exception given on this line.
        _context.Profiles.Add(profile);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return Ok();
    }
```

When I call this controller with `id = "0"` I get the following exception:

```
The instance of entity type 'User' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 0}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.
```

However, if I remove the first SaveChanges() call, this error is not shown.

1st question: Is it intended that entities get tracked after saving changes, wouldn't it make sense that they get tracked beforehand only? Also afaik, add actions don't mark entities as tracked.

2nd question: When is the best time to call SaveChages() in this situation? (It is important to note that add user and add profile actions are in different repo methods in the real project. I simplified the code here.)

3rd question: What is the best way to add foreign keys in situations like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to save whole hierarchy within one call to `SaveChanges`:

```
var profile = new Profile
    {
        Id = "id",
        User = new User { Id = id }
    }; 
_context.Profiles.Add(profile);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

It should answer 2nd and 3rd questions I think. As for the first one - there is a [github](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/9118) issue with request to "Do not track after SaveChanges()".

Since you have different methods you can just set the `UserId` property on Profile (if you have explicitly added it to `Profile` entity) directly.

Comment: I know but as I said, AddUser() and AddProfile() are different methods. I cut the code in 2 methods and put it here. I cant just erase SaveChanges after adding the User because of this one specific use case.

Comment: @M.Azyoksul If they are separate then you will need tracked user, otherwise, AFAIK,  EF will try to add it to database. Use `DbContext.Find` method to prevent possible call to the database.

Comment: @M.Azyoksul or you can just try to set the `UserId` property on `Profile`(if you have added it) directly.

Comment: I didn't know that I have to add a UserId property as well as the User (navigation property). Then I don't set User at all. This solved my problem. Thanks. Anyone that has the same problem should read [this Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key) thoroughly

Comment: @M.Azyoksul was glad to help! And added it to answer.

Comment: Btw, your initial answer causes an unwanted behavior. Setting a new User to the navigation property of Profile creates that user and tracks it in the context (ultimately to be saved on SaveChanges()). This means that you created 2 Users that have the same id and both are being tracked. This again, causes the exception I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @M.Azyoksul my initial answer was for code in one method (sorry, missed that you have separate methods). And my first comment describes exactly that behavior and that you should use tracked user to set the navigation property.

Answer (score 1):

Save the user you create, and then specify that user for the profile.

```
var user = new User { Id = id };
_context.Users.Add(user);
_context.SaveChanges();
var profile = new Profile {Id = "id", User = user};
```